# Google play services uninstalled

Tags: android

I accidentally uninstalled google play services from Android 5.1 device. I had no backup of the app. Then I searched play store for the app, but didn't get.

Now how can I re-install the app?

Comment: http://www.yaabot.com/5332/restore-google-play-store-accidentally-remove/

Answer (score 0):

If you search with query **Google Play Games** in `play store` you should get the first link with the app. 
If not, go in the browser of mobile and search on google **google play games download**.

Go on the below link and download the app from browser.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games&hl=en

Comment: if I install google play games, how it will help me to get back google play services?

Comment: google play games internally needs services, i guess if you install it and run it, might fix services as well.  Give it a shot. I am not 100% sure on this.